# How to set/enable call icon in avd?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want create an avd in eclipse that it have call icon.

This is my [avd](http://www.shiaupload.ir/images/81495331696029650459.png)

I can't make call my avd because it haven't any icon to click for call. i checked my app menu.

Which device should i select that have call icon like show in the pic?

Should i set particular change in my avd?

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer and I'm sorry for users give me the minus...

The answer is level API. For example if you select API 10 you can see the call icon.